# Is it Models or the Database?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

[image]

I'm getting these issues but not sure why I changed the models from in the master branch to as in Project Branch.

This is my DB

[image]

These are my tables
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My project URL:** https://github.com/Bilal815/LWD/tree/Project

Now, what should I do to get going? **I have very little time left!!!**

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a database problem.
https://github.com/Bilal815/LWD/blob/Project/LWD/accounts/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from userAccount.models import User
```

You are overwriting the User import.
https://github.com/Bilal815/LWD/blob/Project/LWD/userAccount/models.py#L7
It does not have the username field and that is what causes the problem